# How to mean to be hosted

Tags: american-english

I'd like to mean a company located in other company adress? I thought the word hosted but it means website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Host* does not always refer to websites. A university can *host* a conference, a family can *host* an exchange student, and a city can *host* the Olympics.

Moreover, the word *host* could be used to talk about one company that is letting another company's personnel work in its building, although there might be other words that would work better. Still, there's nothing ungrammatical about:

> Ever since the hurricane, we have been hosting workers from Acme Corporation until their facilities are repaired.

The word *host* often implies:

- the arrangement is temporary rather than permanent
- the person or organization hosting is providing some kind of service

So, if Acme was paying for the office space at full market rates, a better way to say it might be:

> Ever since the hurricane, we have been leasing office space to Acme Corporation until their facilities are repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Please, post the sentence you are trying to write. *Located* might work as far as we can infer from your question. Or you may consider *the companies share the same address*. 
*To host* is mainly used in relation to websites or people.